# jQuery with selectOneRadio in primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a one page jsf contain a selectOneRadio and I want to associate a jQuery to this component. 
I want for each selected value, a function jQuery start.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
    <p:outputLabel for="console" value="Console:" />
    <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{lotBean.model.type_lot}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One"  />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS+" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U" itemValue="Wii U" />
    </p:selectOneRadio> 
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
(This needs to be in a form)

JSF:

```
     <p:selectOneRadio id="console" value="#{lotBean.model.type_lot}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One"  />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS+" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U" itemValue="Wii U" />
     </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Jquery:

```
var input = $( "form input:radio" )
```